# mysqli_multi_query is repeating the query

Tags: php, mysql

I have several mysql queries in txt files something like:

```
 INSERT INTO foo VALUES (null,name,age);
 UPDATE foo SET name=2,age=30 WHERE id=1;
```

When I place those queries in `mysqli_multi_query` the queries are being repeated. so instead I have 1 insert. I am having 2 inserts.

I will paste my code:

```
include("connect.php");
$myfile = fopen("qlist.txt", "r");
$mydata = fread($myfile,filesize("qlist.txt"));

$myfile2 = fopen("tlist.txt", "r");
$mydata2 = fread($myfile2,filesize("tlist.txt"));


$myFinalData = $mydata.$mydata2;
$msql=mysqli_multi_query($con,$myFinalData);

fclose($myfile);
fclose($myfile2);

@unlink("qlist.txt");
@unlink("tlist.txt");
```

I am certain both txt files got correct mysql queries and not being repeated.

Comment: Executes one or multiple queries which are concatenated by a `semicolon`. in `mysqli_multi_query()`

Comment: Based on what you show us the first query would fail, so I dont understand how you think it is creating 2 new rows. The second query will update any row with an `id=1` how do we know you even have that row as the first query will not work. Do you initialize your table before running this test. Is `id` a unique/autoincrement column? Is there already one or more rows with id=1 in the table?

Comment: 1) Show us your schema. 2) Show us your table BEFORE you start this test. 3) show us the table after you run this test.

Comment: There is basically not enough information in your question for us to do anything other than ___make guesses___

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)